# Implementing a protocol for a client-server socket communication in Java

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm developing a multi-player turn based game for Android - a poker game.
I'm almost finished with the clinet game-play. Now I need to implement the multi-player thing.

I thought about using Web Services but I have no experience with that and I undertsand that socket-communication is faster.

I have some experience with writing socket-communication in Java:
Using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream to exchange data (game-states and turn actions in this case).

But I have a concern with this approach - the server-side is platform-dependent.
If I want to have an iPhone developer create the app for iPhone, he could not do this because the server expects Java code. Am I right?

And another question please:
Can I implement normal-socket communication and then later easily change it to secure-socket communication? It's just that I need to learn how to use SSL and I don't want to go into it right now.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure seems like a simple HTTP-based protocol would be easier. In any case, "sockets" are not platform-dependent. Sockets expect data, in some protocall. Sockets don't "expect Java code".

Comment: If the server expects a custom object (ObjectInputStream.in(CustomObject)), from the client side I would have to use ObjectInputStream.out(CustomObject) in Java. The custom object is written differently in ObjectiveC I presume..

Comment: If you're serializing objects, sure. That's only one way of transferring data over a socket. Sockets expect data; *you* define what data you send and expect to receive, and what to do with it once you have it.

Comment: No. The server should be platform independent. And servers mostly are. Clients adopt to the protocol enforced by the server.

Comment: @greenapps, I guess the protocol is my problem. In my previous project, the client just sent a requestCode (int), and the server sent back data, while the client was expecting specific objects. There was no protocol to enforce anything.. Can you provide a link to explain how to implement a protocol for the clients to "adopt"?

Comment: JSON? Text? Binary? It doesn't matter--pick something. Although IMO this is a layer of unnecessary complexity--what's the specific issue with implementing an HTTP-based protocol?

Comment: @DaveNewton, the issue is lack of experience using http-based protocol. In fact, socket-communication was my first time I used a client-server communication. What do you propose? Sending and receiving JSON objects using HTTP? Wouldn't it be too slow? The players need to poll the server every 2 seconds or so to know if it's their turn etc.

Comment: Your protocol starts where you require the client to send a command as an int. I can not see what you mean with a data object. But it is all up to you what you let your server send. Keep in mind that you send in such a way that all clients can handle it. Of course there is no link if you make your own protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but relevant for me and hopefully others so here goes. I'm currently working on a project that involves multiple computers on different platforms using Java sockets. I'm using sockets because eventually I can use any language as long as I adhere to the protocol I wrote. I too have some predefined integer constants that control what data is expected in what order. For example, before I start some particular function, I send a particular integer, followed by the expected data. Anything that doesn't come in in the expected order results in an error. So as long as the language/runtime offers the ability to write integers and strings over a TCP socket, it should work. I think that covers the vast majority of major programming languages.

As for SSL sockets, I'm doing that also :) I started out using non-SSL sockets and then refactored to make it work with SSL sockets. I was surprised at how easy it is. I would recommend this git repo for sample code: https://github.com/jawi/ssl-socket-demo.

Eventually I plan to have the user who uses my app generate the key store and self-signed certificate locally when they first run the app as part of its initial setup. As long as they import that same key store into the app on every other node that they use in their network, they'll be able to talk to each other. This will ensure that the communication is encrypted in a way that is unique to their network. Of course this will require that they keep the key store file securely stored in their local file systems :)

Comment: It will also ensure that they don't know who they are talking to, so there is no real security.

Comment: @EJP Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate? They could provide their own certificate signed by a verified provider. I could provide one as part of the app as well (and I do plan to sign the jar), but then anyone in the world who uses the app can connect to any computer on any network since they all use the same certificate. What were you thinking could be better?